# CORS issue on accessing API with JWT token

Tags: php, cors, symfony-3.2, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am facing a CORS issue when accessing Symfony REST API from angular with JWT token.

IIS server has been configured to access the application with domain name and IP address. The Front end code is in the same directory of Symfony.

Front end calls API with domain name. Accessing application from IP addresss with JWT token gives CORS issue since API is pointing to domain name.

I have set up response headers with below options in kernel listener.

I am using lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle to generating token(s)

```
$responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept,authorization');
$responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
$responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

I have also set up Nelmio CORS bundle with below options

```
enter code hernelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~        
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600e
```

Response Header:

allow
OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
content-length
0
date
Mon, 13 Nov 2017 16:03:22 GMT
public
OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
server
Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Firefox-Spdy
h2

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "I  am facing a CORS issue" — What issue? Is there an error message? What does it say? What client-side code is triggering it? What do the HTTP request and HTTP response look like?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: Response Header:allow 
OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
content-length 
0
date 
Mon, 13 Nov 2017 16:03:22 GMT
public 
OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
server 
Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Firefox-Spdy 
h2

Comment: Hi, I faced the same issue, did you manage it?

Answer (score 3):

My web.config (Symfony 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="origin, content-type, accept,authorization" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```